# Android Master-Detail from database example

Tags: android, sqlite, master-detail

Is there an example of using the Android Master-Detail flow with the sqllite database? All the samples I have seen use simple lists.

Comment: you need to show some code, what are u aiming to do exactly so we can help?!

Comment: I think this link might be help you. visit <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188650/show-data-in-master-detail-flow>