# Show data in Master detail flow

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

After running a new project on Master Detail flow in  eclipse it shows the dummy items.

I want to replace these dummy items by the data from `SQLite`.

After calling the method of `DBAdapter`(& with the help of Cursor) I was able to print the values in log.

I have no Idea on how to display data stored in  `ArrayList<GetterSetter>` to Master detail flow.

Please tell me what things should be modified in which of classes, or how should I code ?

**UPDATE**

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
static String name = "superstition.sqlite";
static String path = "";
public static ArrayList<GS> a;
static SQLiteDatabase sdb;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} 

private DBAdapter(Context v) 
{
    super(v, name, null, 1);
    path = "/data/data/" + v.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases";
}

public boolean checkDatabase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try 
    {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (db == null) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
}

public static synchronized DBAdapter getDBAdapter(Context v)
{
    return (new DBAdapter(v));
}

public void createDatabase(Context v) 
{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    try
    {
        InputStream myInput = v.getAssets().open(name);
        // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = path +"/"+ name;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) 
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
        // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void openDatabase() 
{
    try 
    {
        sdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public ArrayList<GS> getData() 
{
    Cursor c1 = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM data", null);
    a = new ArrayList<GS>();
    while (c1.moveToNext())
    {
        GS gs = new GS();

        gs.setItem(c1.getString(1));
        gs.setDesc(c1.getString(2));
        Log.v("id",gs.item+"");

        a.add(gs);
    }
    return a;
}
}
```

**GS.java** //getter setter class

```
public class GS {
String item,desc;


public String getItem() {
return item;
}

public void setItem(String item) {
this.item = item;
}

public String getDesc() {
return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
this.desc = desc;
}
}
```

**ItemListActivity.java**

```
public class ItemListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ItemListFragment.Callbacks {

/**
 * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
 * device.
 */
public DummyContent dc;
private boolean mTwoPane;
public ArrayList<GS> q = new ArrayList<GS>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.item_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }

    DBAdapter db = DBAdapter.getDBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    if (!db.checkDatabase()) 
    {
        db.createDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    }
    db.openDatabase();
    q=db.getData();
    dc = new DummyContent();


    // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
}

/**
 * Callback method from {@link ItemListFragment.Callbacks} indicating that
 * the item with the given ID was selected.
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
}
```

**DummyContent.java** // I think that in this static block has to be modified

```
public class DummyContent {
static int i=0;
/**
 * An array of sample (dummy) items.
 */
public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

/**
 * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
 */
public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

static {

    for(i=0;i<182;i++)
    addItem(new DummyItem(""+i, "Item "+i));

}

private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

/**
 * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
 */
public static class DummyItem {
    public String id;
    public String content;

    public DummyItem(String id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
}
```

**ItemDetailActivity.java** // same as generated by eclipse

```
public class ItemDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // savedInstanceState is non-null when there is fragment state
    // saved from previous configurations of this activity
    // (e.g. when rotating the screen from portrait to landscape).
    // In this case, the fragment will automatically be re-added
    // to its container so we don't need to manually add it.
    // For more information, see the Fragments API guide at:
    //
    // http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
    //
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
        // using a fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, getIntent()
                .getStringExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this,
                new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**ItemDetailFragment.java** // same as generated by eclipse

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
 * represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

/**
 * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
 */
private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ItemDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
        // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
        // to load content from a content provider.
        mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(
                ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,
            container, false);

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail))
                .setText(mItem.content);
    }

    return rootView;
}
}
```

**ItemListFragment.java** // same as generated by eclipse

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment {

/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ItemListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why people here are downvoting this question? I have searched over the Internet, & didn't find anything which solves this problem !

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw indeed! this is a good question. I dont know why people downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

You read the data just once, but need a context to do so. It seems a good choice to extend [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html):

#### ItemListApplication:

```
public class ItemListApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String path = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases";
        if (!checkDatabase(path)) {
            File file = new File(path);
            file.mkdirs();
            try {
                InputStream myInput = getAssets().open(name);
                // Path to the just created empty db
                String outFileName = path + "/" + name;
                // Open the empty db as the output stream
                OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
                // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                // Close the streams
                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = openDatabase(path);
        getData(sdb);
        sdb.close();
    }

    private ArrayList<GS> a;

    public GS getItem(int id) {
        return a.get(id);
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<GS> getAdapter(Context context) {
        return new ArrayAdapter<GS>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1, a);
    }

    private final String name = "superstition.sqlite";

    private boolean checkDatabase(String path) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (db == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            db.close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(String path) {
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    private void getData(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
        Cursor c1 = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM data", null);
        a = new ArrayList<GS>();
        while (c1.moveToNext()) {
            GS gs = new GS();

            gs.setItem(c1.getString(1));
            gs.setDesc(c1.getString(2));
            Log.v("id", gs.item + "");

            a.add(gs);
        }
        c1.close();
    }
}
```

and add the class name as attribute to the `<application>` tag:

```
android:name="com.example.myproject.ItemListApplication"
```

This has the effect, that `ItemListApplication.onCreate()` is called once before the data is needed. Also the instance created on application start is available through `getApplication()`.

Since the data in the list is identical to the data in the adapter, `int` can be used to identify the items by position.

Some changes have to be made to your code:

- **ItemListActivity.java**

  - delete fields `dc`, `q`
  - delete everything after the first if in `onCreate()`
  - change `onItemSelected()` to the following:

    ```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
            // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
            // fragment transaction.
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putInt(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();

        } else {
            // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
            // for the selected item ID.
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
    ```
- **ItemDetailActivity.java**

  - in `onCreate()` change how the `arguments` is filled:

    ```
    arguments.putInt(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, getIntent()
                        .getIntExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, -1));
    ```
- **ItemDetailFragment.java**

  - change the type of `mItem` to `GS`
  - in `onCreate()` change the assignment of `mItem` to:

    ```
    mItem = ((ItemListApplication)getActivity().getApplication()).getItem(getArguments().getInt(
            ARG_ITEM_ID));
    ```
  - in `onCreateView()` set the text to `mItem.desc` instead of `mItem.content`
- **ItemListFragment.java**

  - in the `Callbacks` interface as well as it's anomymus implementation change the signature of `onItemSelected(String)` to `onItemSelected(int)`
  - change `onCreate()` to the following:

    ```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        setListAdapter(((ItemListApplication)activity.getApplication()).getAdapter(activity));
    }
    ```
  - change `mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);` to `mCallbacks.onItemSelected(position);` in `onListItemClick()`
- **GS.java**

  - override `toString()`:

    ```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return item;
    }
    ```

Comment: Thank you, It is working ! Furthermore Can you please tell me how can I make list with an ImageView?

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw: Just override `getView` of the Adapter in that case. Also there needs to be a way to load the correct image using the data from `GS` (maybe you have to add a field). For an example see [http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example). Just be sure to remove the `values` field in the code and use `getItem` to access the elements of the adapter. Of course you can change the image in a different way. There should be plenty of questions covering that topic.

Comment: Thanks, I made the list custom, But the Action bar title is not updated when we see detail fragmet, Action bar title should be changed to the name if item selected, it currently shows "Item Detail" for every item description we watch.Please tell me

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw: Use [setTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) for the activity containing the fragment (either `ItemListActivity` or `ItemDetailActivity` depending on whether a large-screen layout is used). `onCreate` of either `ItemDetailFragment` or `ItemDetailActivity` would be the right place (depending on whether you want to change the title in "TwoPane-mode" too (`ItemDetailFragment`) or not (`ItemDetailActivity`))

Comment: For this I raised a qiestion,Can u pls answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300631/how-to-activateshow-currently-selected-item-in-list

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw: The question seems to fulfill your bounty conditions. Please consider awarding the bounty before the grace period ends.